# User Authorization with in MERN

Tags: authorization, mern, user-roles

I am trying to create user roles like admin and users for my MERN project. But, I didn't get any good documentation or resources for it. So, please anyone who know good documentation or resources, suggest me or provide me a good sample of user authorization with MERN stack

Answer (score 0):

You might find it helpful. It explains authentication and authorization in MERN stack on the basis or user roles.

https://abbasimusab2000.medium.com/authentication-with-react-and-node-de7384199a29

Although if you prefer to read official documentation here are few elements that will be useful for both authentication and authorization.

**Backend**
Let's consider you are creating/registering a user you can use [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) for password hashing for security. Once the user is registered you can use bcryptjs function called comparesync to match hash and plain password, next you can create a token using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) and send it to frontend.

**Frontend**
Now on login if the user has entered correct credentials, then the backend will send a token, you can save it in local storage of cookie. For cookies you can use [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie).

Now if you need to add authorization you can send token with request on backend and then the backend will use a middleware for authentication by decoding the jwt and then will execute further logic.

Comment: Can you please direct me to some resources like GitHub repo or beginner-level tutorial that explains role based user authentication using mern stack?

Comment: you can view my repo having both authorization and authentication.
https://github.com/MuqtadirBillah/node-authorization

Comment: Your code was easy to understand. I understood the `/api/auth/login` and `/api/auth/register` routes. After the registration and then login process, a token is given. But I can't yet understand when to use the token. For example, when I send a get request to `/api/user/joke` using postman, it shows the `unauthorized user` error. Can you help me understand how to use the token?

Comment: Tokens can be used for multiple purposes. For example if you are requesting/posting data via an api, the backend can verify your token in middleware and can check if the user in the token is authorized to use this request or not.